# Remove backgroundcssclass of AJAX modelpopupextender with their panel in asp.net using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I want to remove the `backgroundcssclass` of AJAX modelpopupextender with their panel in asp.net using JavaScript. My code working but it is just removing the panel not their `backgroundcssclass`.

I tried a bunch of things but nothing works. I am confused that panel is attached the modelpopextender but then also why it is not removing while remove the panel.

Here is my code

```
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="findpop" runat="server" TargetControlID="btn_find" CancelControlID="Button1" PopupControlID="pnlPromptPopup" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
</asp:ModalPopupExtender>
<asp:Panel ID="pnlPromptPopup" runat="server">
     hello
</asp:Panel>
```

This is the CSS of `backgroundcssclass`:

```
.modalBackground
        {
            background-color: Gray;
            filter: alpha(opacity=60);
            opacity: 0.8;
            z-index: 100;
        }
```

and from above line only panal is removing not their `backgroundcssclass`:

```
document.getElementById('<%=pnlPromptPopup.ClientID%>').style.display = 'none';
```